# How to access another chart in Excel after the first one?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to edit charts in Excel using openpyxl. I am editing because my job has variance in chart types and data, but there is a specific chart format and font my company uses. The code does work for the first chart, but if I try to edit another chart, I get index out of range error.

```py
def graph_formatting(file, font_style = 'Times New Roman', fill_color = "000000"):
    wb = opyxl.load_workbook(file)
    allSheetNames = wb.sheetnames
    ws = wb.active #renders it active
    dechart = ws._charts[1] #the problematic code. 
    print(allSheetNames)
    font_test = Font(typeface=font_style)
    cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_test, sz=1500)
    dechart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(
            p=[Paragraph(
                 pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), 
                 endParaRPr=cp)
            ])

    dechart.x_axis.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = fill_color #changes the line color
    dechart.y_axis.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = False #draws the y axis line
    dechart.y_axis.majorGridlines = None #gets rid of gridline
    dechart.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out' #create tickmarks for x and y axis
    dechart.x_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    dechart.title ='' #deletes the chart title 

    #wb.save(path)
    wb.save(file)
```

If I set `ws._charts[0]`, it works on the first chart sheet. If I set `ws._charts[1]`, I get the list index out of range. I am trying to edit the second chart sheet and hopefully more.

Comment: `ws._charts` is a list of the charts in the current sheet referenced by the worksheet object 'ws'. The first chart on the sheet will be `ws._charts[0]`, the second `ws._charts[1]` etc. If your code sets `dechart = ws._charts[0]` then only the first chart is ever processed and if it sets `dechart = ws._charts[1]` then only the second chart is processed. However if there are no charts or not enough for the list element chosen then an "index out of range" will result. You should be looping the `ws._charts` to get all the available on the sheet if any charts exist or not process if none exist

Comment: Please be mindful of your indenting when posting your code sample(s). Its assumed that every line under 'def graph_formatting(...` is part of that function and should be indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change your code to something like the following;
Use a for loop to loop through the available charts, see the changes to your code sample below;
Use

```
for dechart in ws._charts:
```

So 'dechart' is assigned `ws._chart[0]` on the first loop then `ws._chart[1]` on the second loop and so on for each chart in the sheet.
If there are no charts in the sheet then no processing is done.

This code change covers charts on the same sheet. 
Your code also gets a list of the available sheets but doesn't do anything with that and only works with the active sheet.
There maybe some misunderstanding on the `wb.active` command as you have;

```
ws = wb.active  # renders it active
```

This does not really render anything active (unless you're talking about a worksheet object). This sets the worksheet object 'ws' to the last 'in use' sheet in the workbook when it was last saved. Therefore it may or may not be a sheet with charts.
If you have charts on other sheets in the same workbook or the active sheet is not guaranteed to be one with charts you may need to also loop through the sheets. I.e. select the first sheet, process the chart(s) in that sheet, select the next sheet and so. 
An outer loop is required to do that if that is the desired operation.

```
import openpyxl as opyxl
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties, Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, Font


def graph_formatting(file, font_style='Times New Roman', fill_color="000000"):
    wb = opyxl.load_workbook(file)
    allSheetNames = wb.sheetnames
    print(allSheetNames)

    ws = wb.active  # renders it active

    # dechart = ws._charts[1]  # the problematic code.
    dechart = None
    ### Loop through each chart in the list so 'dechart` is assigned to each chart available. 
    for dechart in ws._charts:

        font_test = Font(typeface=font_style)
        cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_test, sz=1500)
        dechart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
    
        #
        dechart.x_axis.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = fill_color  # changes the line color
        dechart.y_axis.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = False  # draws the y axis line
        dechart.y_axis.majorGridlines = None  # gets rid of gridline
        dechart.y_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'  # create tickmarks for x and y axis
        dechart.x_axis.majorTickMark = 'out'
    
        dechart.title = ''  # deletes the chart title

    # wb.save(path)

    if dechart:  # If there was a chart then save otherwise nothing changed
        wb.save(file)


graph_formatting('chart.xlsx')
```

Comment: Ah shoot, that's why it didn't work. Thank you!